# Access to different sessions tty

Tags: c++, linux

A little bit of context around my question. I am rendering directly to `/dev/fb1` which is attached to an LCD. This LCD also has `/dev/tty0` running. I can render to `/dev/fb1` fine however the blinking cursor of the console obviously disturbs the experience. Thus I am trying to set it into graphics mode.

```cpp
const auto ttyfd = open("/dev/tty0", O_RDWR);
if(ttyfd < 0) {
    log->error("Error opening /dev/tty0: {} (errno={})", utils::error_to_string(errno), errno);
    throw std::runtime_error{"Error opening tty"};
}

if(ioctl(ttyfd, KDSETMODE, KD_GRAPHICS)) {
    log->error("Error setting /dev/tty into graphics mode: {} (errno={})", utils::error_to_string(errno), errno);
    throw std::runtime_error{"Error setting tty to graphics mode"};
}
```

When I run this from an SSH session it is not working, because `/dev/tty0` does not belong to my session and therefore I get `permission denied` in `open`. Running my application as root gives the expected result.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to run my application as root?

Comment: Have you tried sudo?
Or sudo -i -u [userthatrunningtheconsole]

Comment: Yes, that is my current workaround, but ultimately it is the same as running the whole application as root. However I am doing the mode switch in the beginning and then using `setuid` and `setgid` to drop the privileges afterwards.